# How to check if an element is not clickable with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, functional-testing

It's trivial to test if an element *is* clickable with Protractor, but I'm stuck scratching my head trying to figure out how to check if an element is *not* clickable.

I've attempted to wrap the click function in a try/catch so that when an error is thrown when trying to click it should catch it and let the test pass; however, this does not work.

Here is my code for the method that does the check:

```
return this.shouldSeeDisabledFunds()
    .then(function() {
        var clickable = true;

        try {
            fundsElem.first().click();
        } catch (e) {
            clickable = false;
            console.log(clickable);
        } finally {
            console.log(clickable);
        }

        console.log(clickable);

        // All the way through, clickable is still true, and the console log in the
        // catch is not called. I believe this is because click is asynchronous.
    })
;
```

Comment: Does `click()` not return a promise?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have actually figured it out now after realising that. I'll post an answer covering it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for this. As `click()` returns a promise you can simply `.then` off of it and throw in the successful click handler and override the catch handler to do nothing which makes the test pass if the element is not clickable.

```
return this.shouldSeeDisabledFunds()
    .then(function() {
        fundsElem.first().click()
            .then(
                function() {
                    throw "Can click Funds element that should be disabled";
                },
                function() {}
            )
        ;
    })
;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this solution has a side effect of actually clicking the element. It would be nice if there was a solution that could return the information without the side effect.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not applicable in your case, but a better way to check if an element is clickable is checking if it is both visible and enabled: `elem.isDisplayed()` and `elem.isEnabled()`. This way you don't accidentally click on buttons when you're not supposed to.

Fyi, there will be a library coming to help with cases like this: https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1703

Comment: there are other cases which could cause an elemnent no to be clickable, like if a modal dialog is opened on top of it, then even if the element is visible and enabled, wouldn't be clickable.

Comment: Also pointer-events: none; willl make an element unclickable (protractor exception), but elem.isEnabled() will return true

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two methods to check it.

1) Using `ExpectedConditions`

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to not be clickable.
browser.wait(EC.not(EC.elementToBeClickable($('#abc'))), 5000);
```

If found to be clickable, it will return error.

2) Using protractor's `isEnabled`, `isDisplayed` and `isPresent`

So as far as my understanding goes, you can create `isNotClickable`, which will return false only if element is present, displayed or enabled and true otherwise:

```
function isNotClickable(element) {
    return element.isPresent().then((isPresent) => {
        if (isPresent) {
            return element.isDisplayed().then((isDisplayed) => {
                if (isDisplayed) {
                    return !element.isEnabled();
                }
                return true;
            });
         }
         return true;
     });
}
```

Answer (score -4):

To verify Clickable :   **element.isDisplayed().toBe(true)**

Not Clickable : **element.isDisplayed().toBe(false)**

Worked for me.

Comment: An element can be displayed but covered by another semi-opaque element which would receive the click.

Comment: The display property is not related to clickable property. An element can be displayed but at the same time can be disabled. So, this is not the solution.